# Winter Bash 2014 closing remarks - ideas for next year

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash-2015

[Last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213574/180276) we had a question like this, and [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213574/what-should-we-consider-for-next-years-winter-bash#comment802631_213574) SE [staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213574/what-should-we-consider-for-next-years-winter-bash#comment802728_213574) members have supported one this year, and nobody seems to have made one yet.

Hence:

**What does everybody want for next year's Winter Bash?** It's okay to repost old ideas that have already come up if you feel they haven't had enough attention (but please don't go just copy/pasting every [winter-bash-2014](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2014) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)!).

A few ideas I can think of off the top of my head:

- Moar hats! There's been plenty of time to get all the hats this year; it would be great if next year there'd be more to do.
- Keep secret hats secret-er. This could be pretty hard to do, but possibly by deleting/locking "how do I get secret hats" posts?

One idea per answer, please!

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246007/162102

Comment: [Obligatory](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246252/on-the-road-hat-is-americentric): fewer USA cultural phenomena and insignia. :-)

Comment: Maybe post your ideas as answers instead of as part of the question?

Comment: In fact, thinking about it, isn't it _Summer_ Bash for 50% of the Earth...?

Comment: @Eran: that seems like a pointless edit to me

Comment: @Eran: I don't mind that, but it would be much better to perform real edits, if possible.

Comment: @Eran I agree with the other user. That's on the verge of abusing our edit power. For tests we have the sandbox.

Comment: @Eran editing old post? Might be, I got it few hours ago, not sure how. :)

Answer (score 83):

How about making sure that the criteria for hats encourage, you know, *good* or even **exemplary** behaviour.

Not like some of the hats this year (hairboat and the one for posting 5 answers in quick succession spring to mind).

Comment: +1 for pizza-chaser reference ;-)

Comment: What an irony that this question itself was chasing a pizza :P

Comment: Don't be serious, please....

Comment: @Optimizer I'm pretty sure that was the joke. :P

Comment: @rene - you didn't see some of the fallout we had on SO from people chasing hats.

Comment: Relevant post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246007/266359

Comment: The hat that required you to receive at least one downvote on a given day caused several high-rep members on SO to post absolute trash in order to guarantee the downvote. That alone makes me reconsider enabling the hats on SO next year.

Comment: Of course there is Hat Farming, we all know of that, and it is bad. But what about hat Scheming? You find somebody in chat and swap chat stars, down votes, etc. How would that be treated?

Comment: A more problematic was the downvoting hat, some good answers received some downvotes by greedy users who wanted such hat.

Comment: Yet again we have a hat with good intentions (5 edits to post > 1 year old) that is causing problems.

Answer (score 47):

1. [More regular hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245257/244519)
2. [More secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245219/244519)
3. [More stats](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2828262#2828262)
4. [More jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta#comment358200_19492)
5. [More Unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86583/244519)

This was my first Winterbash, and I'd like to thank everyone who participated, and especially the team for doing a great job implementing it. I have a hat to wear for every day of the month now, thanks!

Also, I don't think there should be a Eureka secret hat next year, unless there is at least 24 secret hats, since it's to wishy washy and encourages people to spill the secretz. Definitely not a pizza hat for 5 answers within 30 minutes.  Please have a hat based on comment helpful flags. Another hat based on regular helpful flags. A hat for participating on the site each day during Winterbash, or like every day during December of Winterbash, so that hat awarded on Jan 1st.

Also, allow 1,2, and/or 3 hats to be worn at the same time.

If the team has trouble implementing at least 84 hats (60 regular, 24 secret) next year, they could do a bronze/silver/gold style hat system, where say if you do 10 reviews, you get a Pirate hat, if you do 25 reviews, you get a Parrot to go with your Pirate hat, or just have a new Pirate hat that include the Parrot. If you do 100 reviews, you get a boat with your Pirate hat and parrot.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph.

Comment: yeah the last para is really interesting. Make the hats have "difficulty levels" that add stuff the more you do in that area.

Comment: Unless we implement a better way to handle flags for comments, please no hats for flags. _Please have a hat based on comment helpful flags._ --- I'm going to have to say no to this.  I'd prefer not to have the moderators slammed with flags just for a hat.

Answer (score 24):

Some hats were not possible on all sites (for example, not all sites could have Fascinating Ma'am because not all sites have questions >= 25 score, and 10,000 views).

More consideration should be shown to hats that have 'tough' requirements, and perhaps a 'scaled' or some other 'fairness' threshold should be employed.

Comment: I fully agree with this but this is merely a side effect of badge inequality, and just like it, will never get fixed. Some badges are virtually impossible to earn on smaller sites - and I don't just mean Generalist.

Answer (score 22):

Show the **tag-wikis** some hat luv! AFAIK, there was no hat action relating to curating the wikis.

These are meaningful parts of the SO/SE system. Enhancing them takes a bit of effort, and has lasting value -- moreso than some of the chat/comment activities with hats available. (Although, to be sure, they were a bit of fun and contributed to the festive spirit!)

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised to find out that many people don't even realize they're there. If we make a hat for editing the full wiki, a lot of people will suddenly discover a great resource. +1

Comment: @Shokhet People mostly don't realise they're there because tag wiki activity is invisible until you already know where to look. I think that needs fixing too.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie What would you propose for fixing that? ....bump them to the front page when edited? I'm just wondering why you emphasize "tag wiki *activity*."

Comment: @Shokhet That's the kind of thing that makes post-editing visible in a way that tagwiki-editing isn't. I'm not sure what would fix that — mixed in with question activity would be inappropriate. I'm pondering what might be feasible without being disruptive... but this is probably better tackled in its own meta. :) Oh, and hats for tag wiki edits are a great idea to promote awareness, so +1 anyway!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Maybe a list, in the way-overdone white space on the side of the page, of the most recently edited tag wikis? That would put this activity on the frontpage, *and* keep it from mixing with Q/A activity.

Comment: @Shokhet Yeah, something like that is what I'm picturing.

Answer (score 22):

I think everybody should have equal chances to win all hats. Therefore, please don't make hats that require owning a specific device (iOS only, Android only) or being awake in a specific hour at a specific timezone (which excludes people for which that time happens to be the middle of the night).

Answer (score 19):

Let us search for users with a specific hat. It would be nice to know, for example, who earned Treasure Hunter on my sites this year.

Answer (score 17):

Can we do away with hats that encourage site misuse?

We had people posting deliberately poor questions / answers so that they could be downvoted and deleted this year.

Comment: Duplicate answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246539/59303

Answer (score 16):

I'd like it to be easier to see which hats I've earned *on a particular site*.  Up to nine are shown in the site's leaderboard, and I can find them all by stepping through my hats one at a time to see what sites I've earned them on, but neither of those answers the question "what have I earned *here*?".

Comment: I was gonna post this one!

Comment: @Scimonster I think I posted it last year too.  Maybe this year it'll do better? :-)

Comment: @Scimonster http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213593 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211808/how-can-i-see-what-hats-ive-earned-on-a-given-site

Answer (score 15):

Make the network-wide leaderboard searchable. This is already implemented on the site-specific leaderboards. Compare:

[image: Site specific leaderboard with search]

[image: Network leaderboard -- no search]

(h/t [@Shokhet](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19374929#19374929))

Answer (score 14):

I would opt for hats and other wearables that can be combined. This shouldn't be true for all *hats* but if you have earned a hat and a shirt you can wear them both.

But you can't wear two hats, that is just silly.

You could then have:
 - hats;
 - shirts;
 - glasses (for [Bart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/161198/bart));
 - jewelry;
 - a pond (for the [duck](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245167/infinite-snowflakes)); and
 - snowboots for [cold feets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/bluefeet).

Comment: [*or can you?*](http://filmscoreclicktrack.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/manyhats.jpg)

Comment: [This guy thinks otherwise](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/4794/yez) about wearing multiple hats.

Comment: @Sci not impressive anymore unfortunatly :(

Comment: Or just blue feet because that'd be just awesome!

Answer (score 13):

I would eliminate all the hats that require posting a starred message in chat. Those hats don't encourage participation in the chats, they just pollute the chats with "Can I have a star please?" messages.

Answer (score 13):

As the 2014 Winter Bash leader on Super User with 32 hats, I have to say that Winter Bash was a lot of fun and I learned a lot during my participation. However, I have a few objections with respect to some of the hats.

- The **Imitation Crab** and **Red Shirt** hats [led some users to cast meritless downvotes on several questions](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8960/negative-votes-on-newest-questions). I think Red Shirt can be kept because it stipulates that the post must later be deleted or closed, but Imitation Crab should be removed because it doesn't specify any condition other than five downvotes within a day.
- **30 Minutes or Less** encourages overly broad and opinion-based questions that attract lots of answers very quickly. I was very, very hesitant to even try to get this hat for this very reason, and I think it should be removed. Perhaps the condition should be changed to "*post a question or answer which scores at least +5 within 30 minutes of posting*"?
- **Fear and Loathing** encourages removal of own content. While I took it as a reason to delete my only live downvoted answer, I fear this could encourage users to remove good content and believe it may be a good idea to remove it or change the conditions a bit to avoid this problem. The same holds for **Resolution**.

What I'd like to see next year are more hats for community moderation and useful participation, such as:

- raising at least ten helpful flags
- editing at least ten posts with an improvement in post quality (as determined by the internal post quality score, or by approval of suggested edits)

I ultimately want to see Winter Bash participation as a positive credential for users that can be factored into consideration during more serious events such as moderator elections, so I feel it's important for Winter Bash hats to reflect positive participation and involvement in the community.

---

As **@CRABOLO** mentioned, tiered hats would be a great idea as well. In fact, I would extend the idea by introducing a scoring system akin to a video game "achievements" system. More difficult and higher-tier hats would earn more points, and we can base the leaderboards on this score. This would make Winter Bash more competitive and more fun for everyone.

Ultimately, we must not forget that our goals at Stack Exchange are to provide a high-quality Q&A experience and build a knowledge base for readers. **Winter Bash must align with these goals.**

Comment: Your suggestions for new hats (especially the last one) have the drawback of encouraging people to spend too much time begging for approval of flags/edits, or upvotes on comments, just in order to get hats - as Eran [pointed out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246594/278659).

Answer (score 11):

I'd like some permanent record attached to my profile of the number of winterbashes in which I've participated.  To do this, it could be fun to have a bronze badge given to people each year they participate, in much the same way that people who participate in elections can get the Caucus/Constituent badges (bronze/silver, respectively).

This makes more sense if the hats encourage positive behavior (i.e. asking/providing *good* questions/answers).

Comment: An election is actually a very important part of the site, though. Winterbash is just a fun side-activity and a badge does not encourage anything that just getting the hats doesn't already. We really don't need a bronze badge to tell people to participate in it.

Comment: @animuson I agree that *voting* in an election is much more important than participating in Winterbash.  However, I think that participation in Winterbash could help a site a whole lot more (i.e. bounties, voting, asking questions/answering) than just *loading* the election page and doing **nothing** (see Caucus badge).  If one views badges as a token of "here's something good that I did," rather than an incentive to perform a certain action (I view them as both, while you seem to be emphasizing only the latter), the idea might be more plausible.

Answer (score 10):

I know hats are supposed to be fun and all (and they are!), but there's still a lot of discussion about having them encourage positive behavior. ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246007/266359), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246539/266359))

With that in mind, I'd like to suggest a hat for Meta participation. (*name and shape of hat sold separately*)

The only drawback to this hat, that I'm aware of, is that it would be impossible to get on MSE (*or impossible not to get*), as there is no per-site Meta. However, that hasn't stopped [milliners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatmaking) in the past; this year's "Fascinating, Ma'am" and "Abby Hairboat" hats were impossible to get on a few sites.

Answer (score 9):

Even though the WB ends at a certain date, make the hats and hat stats available for some extra time, if not the full year/ winter season.

Comment: They are. wb2013 stats were available until wb2014 started.

Comment: @nicael where ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214423/the-most-wonderous-hall-of-hats. but no more it works cuz wb2014 already started and even almost ended.

Comment: @nicael what about getting to know other users' hats ?

Comment: impossible..... at least I think so

Comment: @nicael that is exactly what I am asking. So nothing is available right now.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to be able to see the list of hats I earned after Winter Bash is over. I'm not asking to wear them, get badges, etc.  I would just like to look back at my hat earnings, in the same way that I can review any other aspect of my activity.

For example, adding a 'hats' tab here:

[image: stats bar]

The tab would basically show the same thing as the snowflake icon did during Winter Bash.

Answer (score 7):

Bowler hats and top hats!

These and other classic hats are pretty fun to wear. The pixellated bowler hat from 2013 was my favourite. [Capacity for taller hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246573/152515) would naturally be in order.

Also: fancy moustaches to accompany, [perhaps in another hattage slot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246542/152515) (to scale and position the moustache and hat separately).

Maybe next year, a(nother) Watson hat would be in order?

[image: Watson and Sherlock in a bowler hat and... some sort of top hat]
<sup>(Watson (in grey) and Sherlock, from 1984's [The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes_%281984_TV_series%29))</sup>

Comment: +1; though you already *have* a fancy mustache :P

Comment: @Shokhet I do! :) I am privileged enough to have the photoshop capacity to grow one. A moustache to accompany would be no less fun to acquire in a Winter Bash for it.

Comment: Fair :) ....[this guy](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1569/b-a) hung on to the last Watson hat; I wasn't there for that 'Bash (apparently, 2012), though.

Comment: @Shokhet I didn't realise we already had a Watson hat in a previous Winter Bash. Neat! :)

Comment: I wouldn't have known it, either, but the guy wears the hat all year, apparently every year :) ....I was bound to find out about it *sometime* :)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure each hat can be found on each SE. I know you can wear hats from other SEs, but still... for the completionists it's nice to be able to get all hats on their "home" SE. For instance, it was impossible to get Hairboat on CodeGolf.SE this year. I guess, if Eureka comes back, that means the person getting hat should be able to decide where they get it, or just get it on all SEs (it's a pretty rare hat, and quite an achievement, so why not).

Comment: But I saw @Doorknob冰 already got Eureka on Puzzling...

Comment: @user23013 Mods...

Comment: [@Behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/behaviour?tab=allactivity#winter-bash) earned it on [math.se].

Comment: @hichris123 The more you know... my point still stands for Hairboat and the examples in rolfl's answer though.

Comment: hairboat was doable anywhere. Abby had not previously posted on Security. So I asked her to. Then hairboat was quickly acquired :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop - that's not scalable. A sigle person won't be posting on 50-odd sites

Comment: DVK - not a good assumption. Abby was actually very good at helping. She already had posts on many sites, so I would imagine that while there must have been some load on her (not sure how much was automated) it wouldn't be as high as you fear.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to see the Santa hat back. There was some [discussion about there not being a Santa hat this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246119/ho-ho-ho-hat-is-missing).

I think putting a bounty on someone else's question would be a good reason for awarding this hat.

And/or we could make it a secret hat, just for the heck of calling it "Secret Santa".

Answer (score 5):

## Taller hats

The way I tend to put hats on top of my icon meant that many hats this year automatically started shrinking drastically before I got them anywhere near "on top" of my die. The Tardis hat was exciting until I saw that it was just a blue smudge above my avatar in a post's user card.

Besides, the unquestionably best hat last year was Johnny Three Hats:

[image]

And of course, a taller "hat box" around the avatar to fit them in. I was hoping for more excessively tall hats this year, but the "hat box" around the avatar was just too small this year. (Sacrificing tall hats for the (very nice) new placement controls I *do* understand — there's only so much time to implement new code — but I hope tall hat boxes are on the todo list for next Winterbash.)

**Taller hats!**

Comment: And a taller hat box? (Might be worth mentioning all on its own, since I'd like that too regardless of which hats show up!)

Comment: @doppelgreener Yes, and recognition that it was almost certainly cut to make the new placement code implementable in a reasonable time. Added!

Answer (score 2):

Holy *ats, hats are cropped in the review stats:

> [image]

I hope it'll get a fix in a year?

Comment: It looks like they are only cropped when you get them too far off of your profile pic.  How far out does SE need to make the hats appear?

Comment: Oh, derp. I see it now. Yeah, that seems pretty minor considering how many different places we show avatars.

Comment: @psub as far as it is allowed in the hat-chooser.

Comment: @Som yep, situation there is even worse...

Comment: @nicael fair enough.  At least there is a limit

Comment: @psub Unfortunately :D

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestion 1: All hats being obtainable on *all sites***

Kind of like what [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246593/250962) suggests, however focusing on sites. My main focus is the lightbulb and hairboat hats. I was aiming to try and get every hat on [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/). However, to my knowledge, lightbulb is manually awarded by one of the SEx Gods (**S**tack **Ex**change **G**lobal M**od**erators) so even if I did get it chances are it would be here on Meta.

The hairboat hat on the other hand was obtained by posting a comment to a [particular user](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11014/abby-hairboat) and while this user is on [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/155/abby-hairboat), they have no activity which mean the hat associated with commenting to them is unobtainable on Anime and Manga. Now sure, Anime and Manga is in beta, who cares? Well, there are also non-beta sites which would make it impossible for them to obtain (this is going just off from how many questions and answers this user has posted according to [their Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/463168/abby-hairboat?tab=accounts)).

So if a hat is obtainable on one site, it should also be possible to obtain it on any site.

**Suggestion 2: Being able to wear any hat after Winterbash**

It's been suggested in an answer already, but my take would be to be able to wear any hat you have obtained in any previous Winterbash all the time. This can also lead to a more permanent Winterbash site where we can view previous years' hats we obtained (having wardrobe boxes for each year) and also the leaderboards from those years.

The hats then can also be used for other yearly events like April Fools (last year's for example, trading Hats for Bacon and trading Bacon for Unicoins).

**Suggestion 3: Winner Hats**

Who wants a hat from winning Winterbash and show it off all year (extending from Suggestion 2). We can have Winner hats for

- Network Wide Winners
- Local Site Winner
- Total Hat collected Network Wide

Obviously there would have to be a decision on whether network-wide winners can be eligible to also win the other winner hats and/or if winner hats can only be one once per person.

For example, being number one on *[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)*, if the user has more reputation points/time on Arqade they win the hat there and are no longer eligible to win it on *Science Fiction & Fantasy*?

In the example above, the next runner-up would take the winner hat and so on.

**Suggestion 4: Complete Collection Hat**

For completing the collection of hats for one site, sites can opt in to submit a design of their own (Metas get used to vote for the submitted design) and sites which don't opt in and young beta sites (if not all) have a generic one based off the favicon.ico used for the site.

If suggestion 3 is taken on board then hats from it and this suggestion do not count in the leaderboards (if suggestion 2 is taken on board a separate "wardrobe" would store "Special Hats").

Answer (score 1):

How about a hat that is randomly awarded after all users perform a quantity of actions, with the caveat that the user needs to maintain a positive contribution record.  It could be milestone based or completely random.  This would help users who are not active enough feel like that are part of the game when they "win" a hat.

The criteria would be something along the lines of:

- Every 1000th (or 100, or 10000, or more) action for specific task. The actions would take into account every user since Winterbash started.
- If we don't want to live in a base-10 world, we could award it based on specific Milestones in base-8 or base-16.
- Or it could just be completely random.  After the previous hat is awarded, the system could randomly select the next interval.
- Positive contribution record would vary depending on the action, but if the awardee does not have a positive record, no one would get that instance of the hat.

As this is tough to explain, here are couple of specific examples on how this could be awarded (the value of `x` could be different for every action, as some actions are more frequent than others):

- After everyone reviews `x` posts in the close-vote queue, the reviewer who reviewed the `xth` post would get the "random" hat.  A positive contribution record could be no audit failures and no manual review bans since the last random hat was awarded.
- After `x` approved suggested edits, the editor of the `xth` post would get the "random" hat.  A positive contribution record could be no rejected edits since the last random hat was awarded.
- After the `xth` asked question the user that asked the question would be awarded the hate.  A positive contribution record would be defined as no posts (deleted or undeleted) with a net zero less than 0 since the last hat was awarded.
- And there could be others....

Comment: Sounds overly complicated for a hat that everyone will just complain about. No one likes random. [This guy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/9314/random) is questionable enough.

Comment: @animuson true, but the idea was based on drawing people into the "fun" who don't have the time or energy to deal with some of the other quantity based actions.

Comment: If the idea is to help people with little time or energy there's probably a better way than being the xth person to do something, like creating hats with simple and easily achievable criteria. (We had a few of those.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Suggestion 1

I would like to have some hats from previous Winterbash events (2012 and 2013) on next Winterbash 2015. I know in Winterbash SE never kept same hat from previous year (Except Eureka). But I love some of my hats, that was awarded on 2012 and 2013. I would like to see them back on 2015 Winterbash, if possible.

My Favorite Hats Ever:

(The first one is my favorite)

[image: Most Loved Cap]

[image: Helmet]

[image: Glass]

[image: Howdy]

[image: Mustache]

[image: Stallman]

[image: Santa]

#### Suggestion 2

Also it would be better if we have level wise hats (In 2014, there was hats for Gold and Silver badges, but nothing for bronze). New users won't be able to get those two, so it would be better if we have a cap for bronze, a better version of those for silver and the best version of that hat for gold.

#### Suggestion 3

Also it would be nice if we have hats for each review queue.

#### Suggestion 4

Hats for tag-wiki edit and providing tag synonyms

#### Suggestion 5

Hats for successful flags (Moderators will be in pain, if this is introduced :) ) and name it Janitor (Because they are cleaning SE)

#### Suggestion 6

I would like to get hat because of someone others activity (I'm a lazy guy :) ). A suggestion is like 10 profile views or something like that.

#### Suggestion 7

Long term goals for hat, like 1000 reputation in a week, 100 suggested edit reviews, answered 5 days in a week etc. (I suggested it because, I have earned majority of hats in the first week itself. After that I don't have anything to do rather than waiting for January 1st for next hat and changing my existing hat each day. So I think long term goal for hats will be fun)

Answer (score 1):

**Suggestion 1**

Let users suggest the hats for next year. We could post suggestions, and adopt the ones with most up-votes. This will avoid *any* complaint from the users, as they should have brought the matter up earlier. Also, there maybe a few quite innovative suggestions for hats that really require some effort, and will improve the content on the site.

**Suggestion 2**

Add the number of hats to the users's flair. This would especially be good if the gold-silver-bronze hat idea is implemented.

**Suggestion 3**

Create a few 'good user' hats in levels, atleast 5. The actual trigger should be kept secret, as well as random, so users try to contribute in multiple ways, to earn them. So for one user, Good User Level 3 could be unlocked for 5 correct flags, while for another, it could be 3 accepted edits.

**Suggestion 4**

Maybe this one is going overboard, but keep some real reward for the users with most hats. This could be something like 'becoming a moderator for a day' (you could always undo any bad decisions the next day), a badge, 'Winter Bash 20xx champion' or an attractive flair for the rest of the year. This will attract more users (such as I) to compete for all hats, rather than just go after the easy hats.

**Suggestion 5**

Change the name 'Winter Bash' to something like 'Hat Hunt Event' or 'Year-end festival', or something; since not everyone has winter in January. The tropical regions generally have the same moderate climate, while Australia actually has summer.

Comment: No upvotes?? Is my answer not being read enough, or are my suggestions actually that bad?

Answer (score -13):

Personally, I want hats to be displayed in a user's profile.

Comment: Aren't they already?

Comment: @MartinBüttner I haven't seen them...

Comment: Yes, they already are. Just click on their hat count.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcq1I.png