# Use question boards to avoid large number of answers

Tags: feature-request, questions

There a quite a few questions (such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246533/winter-bash-closing-remarks-ideas-for-next-year/246683#246683)) that have an extremely large number of answers, which many people wouldn't bother to read. The answers discuss a variety of suggestions in no particular format.

I have a suggestion for this. SE could introduce a new concept called a question board. It would have no answers, only comments. It would also require a person with more reputation to create it. Anyone could create questions under a question board, generally based on the suggestions given in the comments. Each question would have its own comments and answers, just like any other question.

For example, for the question I referred to in the example, we could one question each, on suggestions for the following categories:

1. Hats
2. Technical bugs and performance
3. Lack of statistics
4. Eureka hat (since there was a lot of discussion over it)
5. ... and so on

For now, if used, I think we should limit it to the meta of the main SE, and only for questions that do not pertain to a specific subject's SE.

Could this work?

Comment: Having questions with many answers should be the exception and not discussion not being supoorted. We are looking for short answers to the point and not discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this right, but isn't this basically what the tagging system already does?

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be as good as our existing system, for one simple reason:

Meta answers force users to create a complete, thorough, justified opinion/solution/response to a topic. A side effect of this is that people tend not to post duplicate answers - but the real effect is that somebody answering has to think.

Comments-only would create a board for offhand thoughts, which people would reiterate and copy, because they're not complete thoughts.

Meta consensus from discussion, for example typically comes of the form: "Should we do [X]?", leading to "[Yes/No], because [reasons]." You wouldn't get that from comments.

For bugs, answers are used to explain why something happened, and what/when the fix was.  Support questions are strictly Q&A. Feature requests are basically glorified discussions.

For small side discussion/fun-only topics, the exisitng system works fine - we don't need to create something new for the rare edge case.

Comment: I'm just saying that many specific questions should asked under a very broad question (such as asking for suggestions). This should only be necessary if the main question is too broad and has maybe 10 or more answers